# How to open an image file in the Android External Storage Directory with Jetpack Compose,?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-permissions

I am migrating a large astronomical application to Jetpack Compose. Several complicating  steps have been taken successfully (migrating the Room Database, the OpenGL views and renderer, several complicated screens etc.)

However, I am not able to implement the basic functionality of reading an image from external storage.

I am using:

```
Android 10
READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is in the Manifest file
Accompanist permission : implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-permissions:0.29.1-alpha"
Coil: implementation "io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.2.2"
```

In this test composable function, the external storage directory is accessible. The file exists with the correct size and the checkSelfPermission test results in permission granted.

But the file is not readable (The image is empty)

I am probably missing something very simple but after several hours, I am out of options and really appreciate your help.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class, ExperimentalPermissionsApi::class)
@Composable
fun SheetContent() {

    val context = LocalContext.current

    val readExternalMemoryState = rememberPermissionState(
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    )
    if (readExternalMemoryState.status.isGranted) {
        Text("Read External memory permission Granted")
    } else {
        AskPermission(permissionState = readExternalMemoryState)
    }

    val path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Download/"
    val file = File(path + "solar-system.png")
    val filesize = file.length()
    
    if (file.exists()) {
        Text("File exist with size: $filesize")
        when (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        )) {
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED -> {
                //File read logic here
                Text("checkSelfPermission gives status: Granted")
                if (file.canRead()) {
                    Text("File can be read")
                    Image(
                        rememberAsyncImagePainter(file),
                        contentDescription = ""
                    )
                } else {
                    Text("File not readable")
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        Text("Not available")
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Read External memory permission Granted
File exist with size: 20534
checkSelfPermission gives status: Granted
File not readable
```

Comment: Update: it works on an Android 12 device.  Why does it not work on Android 10??

Answer (score 0):

Try this download directory path:

```
   val downloadDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but this path produces the same result (does not work)

Comment: It might be because of access permission. As i remember from android 10 and above you can't access other applications files with READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission granted, because of scope storage. You can ask the user to choose the file or if you want to fetch files programmatically you need to get that specific directory access permission from user.

Comment: I "solved" it with a workaround. Using File(context.getExternalFiles(""), "filename"). This will read the file from the sdcard at the local storage in the directory: Android/data/<package name>/files.